# how to shrink image for iphone

Tags: iphone

i can pop up png with some animation but how to shrink same imgae when touch us finished???
right now iam doing this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];


    [self.pieView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

but it just remove the image directly

Answer (score 1):

`-removeFromSuperview` is not an animatable property--it's a method that makes the view disappear. You want to actually instruct the view on how it should animate by manipulating properties on the view such as `alpha` or `transform`.

To ensure the view is actually removed from the view hierarchy when the animation is complete, you can use `+[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:]` and `+[UIView setAnimationDelegate:]`. If you're only targetting iOS 4 and later, you can use two blocks and have much simpler code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
    animations: ^ {
        /* This code is animated. */
        view.alpha = 0.0;
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    }
    completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
        /* This code is run after the animation stops. */
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
];
```

Comment: i am using 3.0 now how i want my image to shrink i the same way as it pop up

Comment: i did it thanks pieView.frame = CGRectMake(g.x  , g.y  , 0.0,0.0);

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner to iPhone. I dont know about animation. But if you use Sprite then you can shrink an image easily using its `scale` property.

Answer (score 0):

well to shirnk i did
pieView.frame = CGRectMake(g.x  , g.y  , 0.0,0.0);